# How to use an numerical input in a form as variable data?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to use the input in one of my forms as the data to a variable on which I can do further calculations. I am trying to use 'getElementbyName' to assign data to the declared variable. But it doesn't seem to pass through.

```
<h3>
    <u>Enter Details Below</u>          
</h3>

<form>
    Enter salary base pay:&nbsp <input type=''text' name='Basic ' />
</form>
<br />
<button onclick='myfunc()'>Submit</button>

<p id='demo'></p>

<script>
    function myfunc() {
    var a = document.getElementByName('Basic').value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (a);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check your console.

Comment: `getElementsByName` is the proper method, [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer - Updated to use input and name attribute as requested.

```js
function myfunc() {
 var a = document.querySelector('input[name="Basic"]').value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (a);
}
```

```html
<h3>
<u>Enter Details Below</u>          
</h3>

<form>
Enter salary base pay:&nbsp <input type='text' id="basic" name='Basic' />
</form>
<br />
<button onclick='myfunc()'>Submit</button>

<p id='demo'></p>
```

Comment: does the [querySelector] require the [id] attribute to be present in order to use that function? Can it not work on the ['Name'] attribute?

Comment: Please see my updated answer using the input and attribute name instead of an id.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementByName` is a invalid syntax. Correct syntax is `document.getElementsByName` (checkout the missing "s").  `document.getElementsByName` returns array, so

Change

```
var a = document.getElementByName('Basic').value;
```

to

```
var a = document.getElementsByName('Basic')[0].value;
```

Also there is a extra single quotes in `<input type=''text'` and extra space in `name='Basic '`. Correct it too,

```
<input type='text' name='Basic' />
```

Your complete code should be,

```
<h3>
    <u>Enter Details Below</u>          
</h3>

<form>
    Enter salary base pay:&nbsp <input type='text' name='Basic' />
</form>
<br />
<button onclick='myfunc()'>Submit</button>

<p id='demo'></p>

<script>
    function myfunc() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('Basic')[0].value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getElementsByName` and get its first result. You also had an extra space in your name attribute.

```js
function myfunc() {
  var a = document.getElementsByName('Basic')[0].value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (a);
}
```

```html
<h3>
  <u>Enter Details Below</u>
</h3>

<form>
  Enter salary base pay:&nbsp
  <input type='text' name='Basic' />
    </form>
    <br />
    <button onclick='myfunc() '>Submit</button>

    <p id='demo '></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works flawlessly now. Can you specify what the '[0]' does?

Comment: The `[0]` selects the first item in the list of elements with the attribute `name` being 'Basic'.